# how to save the node into a array

Tags: c++

I want to use an array to store nodes, and then when I need to use part of the data, I can use the Get function to extract the data (like printing), but when I run it, it shows

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Where is the problem?

```
///node.h
class Node{
 public:
  Node();
  Node(string type, string address);
  string GetType();
  string GetAdd();

 private:
  string m_type;
  string m_address;
};

#endif
```

```
///node.cpp
Node::Node(){
  m_type = "";
  m_address = "";
}


Node::Node(string type, string address){
  m_type = type;
  m_address = address;
}


string Node::GetType(){
  return m_type;
}


string Node::GetAdd(){
  return m_address;
}
```

```
/////main
int main(){
  Node* arr;
  int num_arr = 0;
  string type = "n";
  string address = "003";
  Node* newNode = new Node(type, address);
  arr[num_arr] = *newNode;
  cout << arr[0].GetType() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to allocate the array before accessing its elements.

```
/////main
int main(){
  Node* arr = new Node[10]; // allocate 10 elements
  int num_arr = 0;
  string type = "n";
  string address = "003";
  Node* newNode = new Node(type, address);
  arr[num_arr] = *newNode;
  cout << arr[0].GetType() << endl;
}
```